# Where can I find ic_msg logs?

Tags: solana-test-validator, native-programs

I’m writing a native program and I’m using the `ic_msg` macro with the `solana_test_validator` binary, but I can’t seem to find the log messages. Where do the `ic_msg` logs go? Do I need to configure something on the validator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use solana logs --url localhost in another terminal.

Or you can also set https://explorer.solana.com/ to http://localhost:8899 and look the the logs there. You can add skipPreflight: true in your client if you want to see at logs of failed transactions.

Comment: I tried using `solana logs` but it only shows my successful transactions. Is there any way to see `ic_msg` logs for failed transactions? i.e. ones that go "Transaction simulation failed"

Comment: Oh I understand what you mean by `skip_preflight`, I didn't realize that was an RPC client option. Let me try that out.